# Accessing a Guest Machine's IIS (Installed on VmWare) From Host Browser

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 installed on VmWare Workstation 10 hosting on Windows 7 OS. I have enabled the IIS on Guest machine and I have some applications running there which are accessible through localhost on guest server.

I have run the `netstat -na` on the guest machine and I have these local address
[image]

Now my question is can I access the above address through my host commuter?

thanks

Comment: Yes, as long as both host and guest have IPs that can route to each other. NAT or HostOnly should both work, but I'd recommend NAT. What is the full ipconfig output of the VM?

Comment: Yes, you can. I run NAT for all VM Guest and can see them all from my Host machine and can http to them from any machine on my network.

Comment: I think that is better to write an answer with detail description rather comment like yes, you can. I can't be able that after 1 day trying :(